# Background subtraction in OpenCV / EmguCV with fixed background

Tags: opencv, emgucv

I need some samples / source code for a background subtraction algorithm for using with fixed backgrounds. The background I use is a fixed color background and unfortunately all the samples I've seen so far work for dynamic backgrounds.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about simple frame subtraction? One frame is always the same - it's background, and another frame is frame from videostream. Convert both of them to grayscale and do `absdiff` operation. Here's [my video result](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4herKwkvPk) (look at center frame).

Comment: Thanks Astor. Which one is the background frame? And is it possible to identify different objects based on their colors in a scenario like yours?

Comment: @ÉlodiePetit in video there's no background image of course - it's just image without cars. And yes, you can detect different color objects.

Comment: Thank you. Can you share some source or is it enough to do some research on absdiff?

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that you will suffer from a lot of noise with the subtraction technique. To avoid it, you could always use your best friend in fighting noise: blur, or GaussianBlur.

There's also a fascinating discussion of a statistical approach to this, called 'Code Booking,' in the O'Reilly book "Learning OpenCV."

Another technique for improving your results, provided your intended foreground objects are slow and/or your camera is fast, is to use many images and their differences, as opposed to just two. the programming for that should be easy enough, but as they say in most books: I leave it as an exercise for the reader ;).